# On $\sum_{n_1,\dots,n_k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n_1+...+n_k)^p}$, $p \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the "multiple harmonic series" $$\sum_{n_1,\dots,n_k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n_1+...+n_k)^p}.$$ How can one study the behavior of this series for various values of $p \in \mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: The series converges if $p>k$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949905/does-the-riemann-zeta-function-converge-in-higher-dimensions

Comment: This is rather a zeta type function. Harmonic is confusing or wrong.

Comment: Like a Barnes Zeta function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series can be written
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_{n,k}}{n^p},
$$
where $a_{n,k}$ is the number of ways $n$ can be written as an ordered sum of $k$ positive integers. We have $a_{n,k}={n-1\choose k-1}\asymp n^{k-1}$, so the series converges if and only if $p>k$, and by expressing ${n-1\choose k-1}$ as a polynomial in $n$, the sum of the series is a rational linear combination of the Riemann zeta values $\zeta(p-k),\zeta(p-k+1),\ldots,\zeta(p)$.

Comment: Perfect answer +1

Comment: Why do we have $a_{n,k}={n-1\choose k-1}$ and ${n-1\choose k-1} \asymp n^{k-1}$?

Comment: The formula for $a_{n,k}$ comes from a combinatorial argument called [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: The asymptotic expression comes from the fact that ${n-1\choose k-1}$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $k-1$.