# Convergence of a Riemann Zeta-like Function

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I would like to consider the following sum:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{\substack{\ \ k_1, k_2,...,k_r  \in \mathbb{Z}^d \backslash \{0\}} \\ {\ \ \ \ \ k_1 + k_2 + ... + k_r = 0}} \frac{1}{\|k_1\| \|k_2\| \cdot \cdot \cdot \|k_r\|},$$

where each $k_i$ is a non-zero vector in $\mathbb{Z}^d,$ $r \geqslant 2,$ and $\| \cdot \|$ denotes the usual Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^d.$ I would like to know under which conditions this sum converges (dependent on $r$ and the dimension $d$).

If $r = 2,$ then this sum converges only if $d = 1,$ by comparison with the Riemann zeta function with normed argument (see the link below). But what about for other values of $r$? For instance, does the series

$$\displaystyle \sum_{\substack{\ \ k_1, k_2,k_3  \in \mathbb{Z}^d \backslash \{0\}} \\ {\ \ \ \ \ k_1 + k_2 + k_3 = 0}} \frac{1}{\|k_1\| \|k_2\| \|k_3\|}$$

converge in any dimension $d$?

I suspect that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1954135/363087) result and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1949932/363087) result might possibly be useful here, but I'm not sure how one might implement those results in justifying the convergence (or divergence) of this sum for general $r.$

In the case where $r=3,$ the condition $k_1 + k_2 + k_3 = 0$ lets us replace at most one of $k_i$ in the sum, but from that point, it doesn't seem like there is anything obvious you can do (mainly due to the $\|k_1 + k_2\|$ term appearing in the denominator, if one chooses to replace $k_3$). You can obtain other expressions involving terms like $\|k_1\|^2 \|k_2\|$ by using the triangle inequality, but I don't know what to do with the resulting sums.

Another idea I had was to split the sum into regions in which $\|k_i\| \geqslant \|k_j\|$ for some $i,j,$ and then try to compare it to the Riemann zeta function with normed argument (which I've linked to above). Alternatively, taking $r=4$ (or any even number), then it is possible to bound the sum by a pair of identical integrals over $\mathbb{R}^d,$ which may or may not converge.

Mathematica struggles to deal with the sum even if the indices range over small intervals. However, if $r=3$ and $d=1$, then we get a sum which may converge (it appears to increase very slowly). It appears to approach some value just above 14 in this case.

Comment: It increases with $d$ and with $r$, so it diverges for most values of $d,r$

Comment: @user363087 Do you mean $\mathbb Z^d \setminus \{0\}$ or $(\mathbb Z \setminus \{0\})^d$?  If the former then I agree with user1952009, this seems trivially divergent as you increase $d$ and $r$ because it contains subsums where $\|k_i\|$ can generally be taken small.

Comment: I mean all vectors in $\mathbb{Z}^d,$ not including the single vector $0 = (0,...,0) \in \mathbb{Z}^d,$ i.e. the first one. Do you think there are particular values of $d$ and $r$ for which the sum could converge?

Comment: @user363087 You can reduce to $d=1$ by taking the subset of $\mathbb Z^d$ where only the first component is non-zero.  If that diverges for any $r$ then obviously the larger sum (for $d>1$) will diverge, so I don't see why you are asking about general dimensions.  Similarly, if it diverges for any $r$ then it also diverges for $r+2$ by taking $k_1 = (-1,0,0,\ldots)$ and $k_2 = (1,0,0,\ldots)$.  So again there are very few values of $r$ that are worth considering.

Comment: I see. So that would rule out any even $r$ (given that we know the sum diverges if $r = 2$ and $d \geqslant 2$). Can we say anything about $r = 3,$ then? Is there a similar argument that would prove divergence?

Comment: We have given you all the hint. Now show us what what you get